# Destroying a game object in Arfoundation not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am trying to spawn an object to the ground plane using ARFoundation and then delete the object on a long press.

But the destroy function is not working in this respect.I Have used raycast to identify the object.

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            RaycastHit hit;
            // Check if finger is over a UI element
            if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId))
            {
                Debug.Log("Touched the UI");
            }
            else if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)&&(hit.transform.name.ToString()!= "Quad"))
            {
                if (Input.GetTouch(0).deltaTime > 0.2f)
                {
                    Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                PlaceObject();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this code from first if statement;

```
Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began
```

Because if it is there, your function will called only one time when start of touching.